# How to convert DELETE records based on Inner SELECT query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Below is my SELECT query :

```
SELECT Data.VendorProductRateID    
FROM
(SELECT MIN(VendorProductRateID) VendorProductRateID
FROM TMP_VendorProductRate
WHERE VendorProductID = 4
  AND VendorProductRateTxnInfoID = 89
GROUP BY DialCode,StartTime) Data,
TMP_VendorProductRate TMP_VendorProductRate
WHERE (TMP_VendorProductRate.VendorProductRateID = Data.VendorProductRateID);
```

Result :

```
VendorProductRateID
123
124
125
```

My table has 50 records so now I want to DELETE all record without above 3 ids.

I have tried with below query but not able to DELETE records :

```
DELETE FROM `TMP_VendorProductRate` AS CHC  WHERE CHC.VendorProductRateID NOT IN
(
    SELECT Data.VendorProductRateID
    FROM
        (SELECT MIN(VPR.VendorProductRateID) VendorProductRateID
            FROM TMP_VendorProductRate VPR
            WHERE VPR.VendorProductID = 4
                AND VPR.VendorProductRateTxnInfoID = 90
            GROUP BY VPR.DialCode,VPR.StartTime
        ) 
    Data,
    TMP_VendorProductRate TMP_VendorProductRate
    WHERE (TMP_VendorProductRate.VendorProductRateID = Data.VendorProductRateID)
)
```

Error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS CHC  WHERE CHC.VendorProductRateID NOT IN
(
    SELECT Data.VendorProductRa' at line 1

Comment: Any error coming or what?

Comment: Yes error comming in DELETE query.

Comment: Share that error too..

Comment: And not in the comments

Comment: Added error in Question.

Comment: TMP_VendorProductRate TMP_VendorProductRate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi see the delete query syntax here,

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_delete.asp

Alias name will not come for `DELETE` query, Change like below,

```
DELETE FROM `TMP_VendorProductRate` WHERE...
```

may this will help

**UPDATE**

Without alias name you can give,

```
DELETE FROM `TMP_VendorProductRate`  WHERE VendorProductRateID NOT IN
(
    SELECT Data.VendorProductRateID
    FROM
        (SELECT MIN(VPR.VendorProductRateID) VendorProductRateID
            FROM TMP_VendorProductRate VPR
            WHERE VPR.VendorProductID = 4
                AND VPR.VendorProductRateTxnInfoID = 90
            GROUP BY VPR.DialCode,VPR.StartTime
        ) 
    Data

    WHERE (TMP_VendorProductRate.VendorProductRateID = Data.VendorProductRateID)
)
```

Try this...

Also please tell me `TMP_VendorProductRate TMP_VendorProductRate` this means?

Comment: But I need delete based on NOT IN condition means using sub query and also with same table.

Comment: Thats no pbm, you can try without alias name@SanjayChaudhari

Comment: It will show error : #1093 - You can't specify target table 'TMP_VendorProductRate' for update in FROM clause